# Web page goes black after it is done loading on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Does anybody else have this? It started today, with google.com among other webpages. It shows the page loading, and after it is done the whole page goes black.

I can interact with the links and text on the page (e.g. really wanted to read a page so I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and copy/pasted it in `gedit`).

I think it started just after I updated with the package manager, but I didn't look if chrome-stable had an update (flash did though).

Comment: Have you tried a different browser?

Comment: @Mitch it happens randomly. Now I'm using Chrome to write this.

Comment: Do you have webGL enabled, and what plugins/addons do you have?

Comment: @handuel I haven't had any changes to Chrome ever since I reinstalled Ubunt 12.04 about a month ago. And I checked in chrome://flags and it's enabled

Comment: @Silviu This may sound odd, but try disabling it temporally by running this from the terminal: chrome --blacklist-webgl --blacklist-accelerated-compositing --disable-3d-apis --disable-webgl this will only apply these changes for a single run, but see if that fixes it.

Comment: chromium-browser --blacklist-accelerated-compositing Works on 13.04 as well.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 12.10, this worked:

```
chromium-browser --blacklist-accelerated-compositing
```